# Progress bar withing a foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method that iterates through an array of music notes and plays them one after the other. I have created a progress bar that will show the status of the foreach loop.
The problem is that the progress bar is not filling up to 100% but approximately till 85%. I have also noted that the progress bar is progressing roughly, I think that this could be because the steps are large. Any ideas on how can I optimize this progress bar, pb is my instance of the progress bar, Thanks

```
    public void PlayAll()
    {
        pb.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(CountTotalDuration());  //Total lenght of the full song.
        pb.Step = Convert.ToInt32(CountTotalDuration()) / Convert.ToInt32(ListSize()); //Total lenght of each note making up the song.
        foreach (MusicNote m in list)
        {
            m.sp.Stop();
            m.sp.Play();
            Thread.Sleep(m.NoteDuration*100);
            pb.PerformStep();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds strange, I didn't find the problem, but I suggest you can try as this:

```
public void PlayAll()
    {
        pb.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(ListSize());  //Total lenght of the full song.
        pb.Step = 1;
        int i = 1;
        foreach (MusicNote m in list)
        {
            m.sp.Stop();
            m.sp.Play();
            Thread.Sleep(m.NoteDuration * 100);
            pb.Value = i++;
        }
    }
```

further more, maybe you should use multithreading to improve the user experience, because Thread.Sleep() makes the form like dead.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is from rounding errors in your steps. Lets look at a simple example, say you have a `CountTotalDuration()` of `100` and a `ListSize()` of `7`

because you have two integer numbers `/` does integer division and throws away any remainder so `100 / 7` equals `14` (instead of `14.285714` with `285714` repeating). That makes your step size 14, so after doing 7 steps your total value you have reached is `98` and you would see 98% on the toolbar.

Since `CountTotalDuration()` appears to be the sum of `NoteDuration` the way to fix this is to not use equal step sizes each step. Instead, just set the max to the total duration and increment the bar by the tote duration. This will make the bar jump in proportion to the position in the song based on note length.

```
public void PlayAll()
{
    pb.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(CountTotalDuration());  //Total lenght of the full song.
    int currentCount = 0; //Initialize our counter to 0.

    foreach (MusicNote m in list)
    {
        m.sp.Stop();
        m.sp.Play();
        Thread.Sleep(m.NoteDuration*100);

        //Increment the counter proportional to the length of the note.
        currentCount += m.NoteDuration;

        //Set the progress bar using our calculated position.
        pb.Value = currentCount;
    }
}
```

You still are going to have big jumps when long notes play, the only way to solve that is not use `Thread.Sleep(m.NoteDuration*100);`  and instead use multiple shorter pauses and update the bar in between those pauses. Also `Thread.Sleep` may not be the best way to pause the loop, but I don't know what the best alternative to use instead would be, it depends on a lot of details which you have not shared with us.

---

You could also have similar behavior to your old method and have the note jump by 1 for each note played and just make the bar's maximum equal to the number of notes you will play.

```
public void PlayAll()
{
    pb.Maximum = list.Length; //Or equivalent, perhaps ListSize()?
    pb.Step = 1;

    foreach (MusicNote m in list)
    {
        m.sp.Stop();
        m.sp.Play();
        Thread.Sleep(m.NoteDuration*100);
        pb.PerformStep();
    }
}
```

This will give you more even jumps per note but if the song is only a few notes long those even jumps could still be very large.